# Unable to cd into the directory through cmd window in Java

Tags: java, cmd, execute

My goal is to get the path of the .db file generated by the application under test.

File is stored in a location below, where folder name in which the test.db will be saved is keep changing every time i run my test
C:\Users\TestAcc\Documents\Application\2017-12-01T14-25-49\test.db

Following is the code I have tried to see if I can get the path of the folder in which the .db file is saved, The output I am getting for this code is the directory location where from the test script is running

```
try
        {

            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c \"cd C:\\Users\\TestAcc\\Documents\\Application\\2017* && echo %cd%\"");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            while((line = br.readLine())!= null)
            {
                System.out.println("Current Directory - " + line);
            }                   
        }
catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: Why do you need a shell process for that? Can't you do it in Java?

Comment: I am new to Java, can you point me to any documentation that would help me

Comment: You want to find a certain folder, right? Use the method `File.listFiles()` on the parent folder, and iterate through the `File` objects until you find the right one.

Comment: Thank you so much, that helped a lot. Now, I am able to get the path I needed

Comment: No problem... :)